# Psychtoolbox issue after recent Mac update

Tags: macos, psychtoolbox

I recently got an update (macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 Update), and it seems to have messed with the display a bit.

I use Octave (v4.2.2) to run experiments off of my laptop (MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5), which requires me to put images on the screen (Psychtoolbox v3.0.14). Since I updated my computer the script errors out at the point where I attempt to put anything on the screen. Unfortunately, because of a bug with Octave, I can't see an error message, so I don't know the exact nature of the problem.

Apart for this problem with Octave, the screen randomly switches to "static" (like the old school TVs!). This only lasts for half a second before it switches back. But I can't help but wonder if both problems have a common root.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Mrinmayi

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you think your issue is related to a recent MacOS update, your question is most likely more suitable for [apple.se] or [su]. If you think the issue is related to your code, then your code should be in the question so someone can use it to attempt to reproduce the issue. You may want to spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask].

Comment: What is the 'bug with Octave' that prevents you from seeing the error message?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what it is. I've just been working around it. I'm using the --no-gui option since the gui has also been crashing a lot. But when I run a script and Octave encounters a problem, it stops execution but I can't see any error messages. I assumed that it was because Octave was unstable on my current OS.